# Is there a way to name arrow functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions

I'm using arrow functions in an app and sometimes there is the need to get a reference to the function itself. For normal JavaScript functions, I can just name them and use the name from within. For arrow functions, I'm currently using `arguments.callee`. Is there a way to name arrow functions so that a reference can be used from within?

#### Sample code

```
// TypeScript
private evaluateIf(expr: parserModule.IIfExpression, callback: IEnvCallback) {
    this.evaluate(expr.condition, proceed => {
        guard(arguments.callee, arguments, this);
        if (proceed !== false) this.evaluate(expr.then, callback);
        else if (expr.else) this.evaluate(expr.else, callback);
        else callback(false);
    });
}

// JavaScript
Environment.prototype.evaluateIf = function (expr, callback) {
    var _this = this;
    this.evaluate(expr.condition, function (proceed) {
        guard(arguments.callee, arguments, _this);
        if (proceed !== false)
            _this.evaluate(expr.then, callback);
        else if (expr.else)
            _this.evaluate(expr.else, callback);
        else
            callback(false);
    });
};
```

What I settled on after the assistance since arguments might not be there forever:

```
private evaluateIf(expr: parserModule.IIfExpression, callback: IEnvCallback) {
    var fn;
    this.evaluate(expr.condition, fn = proceed => {
        guard(fn, [proceed], this);
        if (proceed !== false) this.evaluate(expr.then, callback);
        else if (expr.else) this.evaluate(expr.else, callback);
        else callback(false);
    });
}
```

Comment: Isn't the main point of arrow functions just a more succinct way of expressing anonymous functions, with the correct `this` binding? Hence they wouldn't have names with the JS equivalent anyway.

Comment: Looks like you don't want arrow functions after all, but a named function expression.

Comment: Nah. Actually I want to use the arrow functions and they are working well. However I'm implementing a piece of code (following a tutorial) that requires that I use the calling function as part of a `guarding` process. I want to know the way to avoid using arguments.callee while at the same time avoiding having to go and change each function that is affected to a normal javascript function.

Comment: named functions are also handy for stack traces aside from needing to reference them

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is there a way to name arrow functions so that a reference can be used from within?

Not unless you assign it to a variable. For example:

```
var foo = () => {
    console.log(foo);
}
```

> For arrow functions, I'm currently using arguments.callee

`arguments` are not supported by arrow functions. TypeScript currently incorrectly allows you to use them. This will be an error in the next version of TypeScript. [This is to keep TypeScript arrow functions compatible with the JavaScript Language Specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1609).

**For your use case I would just use a `function`.**

Comment: Oh ok. So my code is working now because typescript is currently not converting them to es6. Since typescript is converting it to plain javascript, is there a way to get it to assign a name to the function it generates? I have some sample code so will edit the question and add it since it is not well formatted

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. `arguments` are going to be an error irrespective of which version (es6,es5,es3) you are targeting. I've updated my answer

Comment: @ritcoder I've also added a code sample to explain what I meant with assign to a variable

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that. I guess I'll have to use normal functions for those portions then.

Comment: Yeah. As in your code sample, it actually worked expect that I had to declare a variable outside the function to use it but I'm ok. I've edited the question to show the updated code.